# MAPISendMail Thunderbirdで本文の一部が消えてしまう

Tags: c++

MAPISendMailでThunderbirdのメール編集画面を表示しています。

本文に<checkCode:F995>という文字列が有るのですが、編集とアドレス入力の設定で、HTML形式でメッセージを編集するとしていると、この文字列が消えてしまいます（このチェックを外すと正常です。）

HTML形式のまま、この文字列が消えない様にする方法をご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbirdの設定により、本文の<を&lt;に変換、>を&gt;に変換したら表示されるようになりました。